# Upload a json object to S3 using Clojure?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, clojure

I am trying to figure out how I would upload a Json object to S3 using clojure through lambda. I am not doing any json type checking and I am just trying to write a handler such that as soon as receives a json object, it uploads that object to the bucket. Here is my code:

```
(ns clojurehandler.s3_clojure_handler
  (:gen-class
   :name "clojurehandler.S3ClojureHandler"
   :implements [com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler])
  (:require [clojure.data.json :as json]
            [clojure.string :as s]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [aws.sdk.s3 :as s3]))

(def cred {:access-key "..", :secret-key ".."})

(defn handle-event [event]
  (s3/put-object cred 
                 "bucket-name" "name" event 
                 :content-type "application/json"))

(defn -handleRequest [this is os context]
  (handle-event (io/reader is)))
```

I am using this library: https://github.com/weavejester/clj-aws-s3
which I know has been deprecated but it seems like it should do what I am aiming to do.

I have already set the role of my lambda function to enable putting objects in S3 buckets, but I get a task timed out after 3 seconds error when I try to test it. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Please add the stacktrace of the error or anything else that would help to identify it.

Comment: Timeouts generally indicate networking problems. Are you running your Lambda inside a VPC? If yes, you need to either (1) run it on a subnet that has a NAT, or (2) add a VPC endpoint for S3.

Comment: Also, does it work from the REPL on your machine?

Comment: Lastly, I'd use the actual AWS SDK, rather than a wrapper library (although _weavejester_ is certainly a good source).